# Calculate bandwidth using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, bandwidth, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to use `AFNetworking` to get a rough estimate of upload bandwidth. I have a subclass of `NSObject` observing the `AFNetworkingOperationDidStartNotification` and `AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification`'s. I get the total expected bytes to write in my `AFHTTPRequestOperation` progress block:

```
    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        if (lastUploadSize != totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
            lastUploadSize = totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    }];
```

On did start and finish, I save the current date into their respective iVars. I then call a method, `calculateBandwidth` which does some simple calculations:

```
-(void)calculateBandwidth {
    NSTimeInterval difference = [uploadFinishTime timeIntervalSinceDate:uploadStartTime];
    float bandwidth = (lastUploadSize * 0.0078125) / difference;

    PLog(@"Bandwidth (calculated): %f kbps", bandwidth);
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(networkClientDidUpdateBandwidth:time:withSize:)])
        [_delegate networkClientDidUpdateBandwidth:bandwidth time:difference withSize:lastUploadSize];
}
```

But the bandwidth results seem to be off. 0.0078125 kilobits = 1 byte if I'm not mistaken; am I missing something in the math?

I plan on making a more complex bandwidth detector using a similar method, but for now want to get accurate upload bandwidth on a per upload basis.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with the code. Try inspecting the lastUploadSize. If you get a size with a sane value, the problem likely lies in AFNetworking itself. If it is absent, the problem lies with the server.

Comment: BTW, if you want effective bandwidth measure, that's fine. But if you want actual bandwidth, you may want to isolate the network latency of the initial connection with the server from the bandwidth (e.g. don't start your timer before you start the connection, but do it in `setUploadProgressBlock`). I'm not sure this is a distinction you even care about, though...

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you found a better way to do this?